# Encountering a formidable plugin error within Nextjs 13

Tags: next.js, formidable, next.js13

I am getting this error when using Formidable with NextJS 13:

```
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression // error

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/formidable/src/Formidable.js
./node_modules/formidable/src/index.js
./app/api/rest/file/route.ts

error - Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\jacob\Documents\GitHub\pim-nextjs-ts\yakpim\.next\server\app\api\rest\file\plugins\octetstream.js'
```

This is the code block:

```
     export async function POST(request: NextApiRequest, response: NextApiResponse) {
        console.log("success"); // this works
    
        const form = formidable({ multiples: true }); // this triggers the error
```

I have tried yarn update formidable as well as ''yarn remove'' and ''yarn add'' again. No fix on the error.

In the node_modules > formidable folder I can see the plugin is added and used but this causes an error.

Wondering if anyone else has encountered and how you managed to resolve?

Thanks!

yarn update - no fix

yarn remove & yarn install - no fix

Comment: try `npm install formidable@v3`

Comment: Hi @Joe, Thanks! That worked. Not sure how I didn't see v3 but anyway. Onto the next problem. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since formidable couldn't handle it, I imported the file directly from formdata and saved it.

In the request's formData, we converted the File object to a Buffer and stored it.

Below is an example of how this is done to save an image.

```
export const POST = async(req: NextRequest) => {
    const f:any = await req.formData();
    const obj = Object.fromEntries(f);    

    Object.entries(obj).forEach( async([k, v]) => {
        if( !!v.type ) { // If it's a file, values like image/png are passed over.
            const b = await v.arrayBuffer();
            const buff = Buffer.from(b);

            fs.writeFileSync(`./public/${k}`, buff);
        }
    });
}
```

If you have a fixed key value without having to convert to Object.fromEntries, you can use the

```
const fileObject = f.get("filename");
const b = await fileObject.arrayBuffer();
const buff = Buffer.from(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it for you، but I didn't use **formidable** scripts، but I first downloaded the file to base64، then created an image using the **node-base64-image** library، which works.

```
import { Buffer } from 'buffer';
import { decode } from 'node-base64-image';


function makeid(length = 10) {
    var result = '';
    var characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    var charactersLength = characters.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
    }
    return result;
}

export async function POST(req) {
    try {
        const formData = await req.formData();
        const file = formData.get("file");
        let namefile = makeid(10)
        // Read the file data as a Buffer
        const fileData = await file.arrayBuffer();
        const buffer = Buffer.from(fileData);
        // Convert the buffer to Base64
        const base64Data = buffer.toString('base64');
        await decode(base64Data, { fname: "./public/upload/" + namefile, ext: "png" });
        return new Response(JSON.stringify({ success: 'File converted to Base64 successfully' }));
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return new Response(JSON.stringify({ error: "Server Side Error !" }), {
            status: 500
        })
    }
}
```